# Injectivity of div–curl operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

$\DeclareMathOperator\div{div}\DeclareMathOperator\curl{curl}$Consider a div–curl system
\begin{align*}
Lu &= (\div(u), \curl(u)) \text{ in } \Omega \subset M, \text{ a 3-manifold}, \\
u &= 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega.
\end{align*}
Here, $u$ can be a $p$-covariant symmetric tensor field, $p \geq 0$. These are defined to be $(p-1)$-covariant and $p$-covariant, respectively by:
\begin{align*}
     \div(u)_{a_1 \cdots a_{p-1}} &= \nabla^a u_{a_1 \cdots a_{p - 1} a} \\
     \curl(u)_{a_1 \cdots a_{p}} &= {\epsilon}_{a_1}^{\ \ \ \ ab}\nabla_a u_{b a_2 \cdots a_p}.
\end{align*}

The operator $L = (\div, \curl)$ is a first-order elliptic operator. Is it known whether or not this operator is injective in various natural settings (e.g. on a compact Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, on an unbounded complete Riemannian manifold, weighted/unweighted Sobolev spaces…)?

In, for instance, flat space $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ bounded, $L$ is injective on the domain $H^k_0(\Omega)$ (trace-zero vector-valued functions in $H^k(\Omega)$), this follows from the vector calculus identity $\nabla \times (\nabla \times v) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot v) - \Delta v$. If $\div(v) = 0$ and $\curl(v) = 0$ with $v \in H^k_0(\Omega)$, then $\Delta v = 0$, and this implies $v = 0$ since the Laplacian is injective in this setting.

However, in a curved space this vector calculus identity gives only
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{curl}^2 (v)_a = \nabla_a \operatorname{div}(v) + R_{ae}v^e - \Delta v_a
\end{align*}
and the resulting equation obtained from the divergence and curl vanishing is
\begin{align*}
\Delta v_a - R_{ae} v^e = 0,
\end{align*}
and I am not sure of the injectivity of the operator $-\Delta + \operatorname{Ric}$.

Edit: I think for vector fields on Riemannian manifolds you have the same result if the topology is trivial: by the Poincaré Lemma, if the curl of $v$ is zero, the it is equal to the gradient of a potential function $\phi$; the divergence being zero then gives $\Delta \phi = 0$. Assuming that the spectrum of $-\Delta$ is positive (a result known for $M$ a compact manifold; I'm unsure if it holds for bounded domains), this would give the result. However, 1) I'm unsure, as just mentioned, of this positivity of the spectrum of $-\Delta$ for non-compact manifolds/manifolds with boundary; and 2) the question is still unresolved for higher-rank tensor fields.

Comment: Does the [Hodge decomposition of forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Hodge_decomposition) answer your question? It sounds like you're taking part in the time-honored tradition of accidentally rediscovering de Rham cohomology!

Comment: @DanielShapero - I think Hodge decomposition is sort of what I want, but I'd like some analogous statement for (not necessarily alternating) tensor fields. Are you aware of any such extensions?

Comment: Hm there are other complexes besides the de Rham complex. For example there's a cochain complex associated to the linear elasticity problem, for which one of the spaces consists of symmetric tensors; see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-07-01998-9).

Comment: For compact manifolds, you already have a fairly trivial obstruction: the Riemannian metric itself is both curl-free and divergence free. (Interestingly this is ruled out if you look at manifolds with boundary or non-compact manifolds, the latter using decay at infinity.). This extends to all $p$ even.

Comment: There are _some_ sufficient conditions for injectivity following from the Bochner argument. For example, if the manifold is conformally flat (vanishing Weyl curvature; this condition can be replaced also by a sign condition on the Weyl curvature that is harder to state) and has non-negative Ricci curvature, then any element in the kernel must be parallel; if in addition Ricci is strictly positive at at least one point, then the the kernel can contain only those tensors built from symmetric products of the metric with itself.

Comment: (If that sort of result interests you, I can type out a bit more details; let me know.)

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong - in the noncompact case, assuming decay at infinity, you mentioned that the trivial obstruction (the metric itself) is no longer a counterexample. Of course it's a big step to then say the kernel is trivial in the non-compact case- but do you know if this is known? Or any resources that discuss it?